# Generate file on client machine using sql and Qprocess in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have to generate a file containing database query result on a client machine (database server is on other machine ) using mysql through c++ code in Qt .

I am trying to use QProcess to achieve it ,but it generates file on server machine not the client machine ...I want that resultant query result file  should be generated on client machine.

Comment: Which operating system (both local and server)? How are you able to upload to the server, through SSH, Telnet, FTP, HTTP? Because that's not really a Qt or C++ problem... That's either a database access problem, or a file transfer problem.

Comment: What database do you use, is it sqlite?

Comment: I am not familiar with what Qt and QProcess offer, and not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I think there may be an ODBC connector that would allow you to fetch data from a server.